# Issue with Elastic Beanstalk, Immutable Deployments, and CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

We have just recently begun using immutable deployments with Elastic Beanstalk. To be more specific, we enabled

- immutable application deployment and
- immutable configuration updates.

We use CloudFormation for everything. E.g., instead of enabling immutable deployments using the UI (AWS Management Console), we added the respective `OptionSettings` to the `ConfigurationTemplate` within our configuration template.

However, we ran into some issues using this approach. Whenever we change certain properties within the `ConfigurationTemplate`, we get this error message:

> Failed to deploy application.
>
> Cannot update resource configuration and instance configuration simultaneously with immutable deployments. Choose a different deployment policy and redeploy to make this change.

After intensively searching the documentation, we were not able to find out exactly *what* changes we may do with immutable deployments, and what causes the above error. We got the error when we tried to manipulate the following `OptionSettings` property:

```
- Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg'
  OptionName: MinSize
  Value: 6
- Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg'
  OptionName: MaxSize
  Value: 6
```

We would be very thankful for anyone who could tip us off in regards to *what* options we might change within our CloudFormation template without causing the deployment to fail. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

You need to set your aws:elasticbeanstalk:command DeploymentPolicy to "Rolling" or something else and push that through.  Then you can change it back to Immutable once it is set to something other than the default and not Immutable.

The message means that you are not allowed to change them both to on at the same time but not that they can't be used together.

Also make sure you have aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate RollingUpdateEnabled set to true plus aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system SystemType set to "enhanced" and configure a aws:elasticbeanstalk:application Application Healthcheck URL in your app for it to health check otherwise it will fail with another misleading message.